# Querying From MySQL Using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to query a MySQL database table. I am using NodeJS / Express as my backend.

I have set up the MySQL like this.. (Yes I have checked to see if the backend connects to the database. I have just left out the credentials below.)

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '',
  user: '',
  password: '',
  database: ''
});

db.connect((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("MySQL connected.");
  }
});
```

I'm trying to keep my code organized, so I have this in a configuration file. I want to export the db constant and do db.query() from other files.

Therefore, I have done this.

```
module.exports = {
  app: app,
  db: db
};
```

However, when I require db in other files doing the following

```
const db = require('../../server');
```

It says db.query is not a function. Anyone know why it would say that? I can't seem to get it export correctly most likely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application I use it this way:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: '***',
    user: '***',
    password: '***',
    database: '***'

});

module.exports = connection;
```

And where I need to call it :

```
const conn = require('path/to/dbfile.js');
```

Then just use:

```
conn.query('SELECT * FROM TEST', function (err, rows) {
    if (err)
        return err;
    return rows;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## The short answer

You probably have a circular dependency, i.e. you have a file `a` that `require`s file `b`, but file `b` also `require`s file `a`. In combination with using `module.exports = something` (instead of modifying the existing `exports` object), this leads to the situation where one of the modules will get an empty object returned from `require`ing the other one (none of its exports seem to exist there).

The quick fix is most likely to replace `module.exports = { app, db }` with `exports.app = app; exports.db = db` or `Object.assign(exports, { app, db })`.

As to why, and what other options exist in case that is not the best solution, read below.

## The long answer

It sounds as if you have a circular dependency problem.

Let me explain, and bear with me, we'll eventually get to your problem.

See, every module starts out with an empty object as `module.exports` (also available as `exports`). If you only *modify* this object by doing `exports.something = something` (or `module.exports.something = something`), things can work in many cases even with a circular dependency at the top level, as long as the properties of the exports object are accessed only later on. For example:

```js
/* a.js */
const b = require('./b')

exports.getX = function () {
  return b.getY() * 2
}

exports.getZ = function () {
  return 5
}
```

```js
/* b.js */
const a = require('./a')

exports.getY = function () {
  return a.getZ() * 3
}
```

```js
/* main.js */
const a = require('./a')

console.log(a.getX()) // Returns 30
```

Here we have a circular dependency (`a` depends on `b`, but `b` also depends on `a`). Yet, it works.

The above code works because when `a.js` is evaluated, its `exports` object will already exist, and when it then requires `b.js` and `b.js` requires `a.js` again, then even though `a.js` has not even finished running its top-level code yet, the `a` variable in `b.js` can already get assigned the `exports` object of `a.js`. It is an empty object at that point, but by the time the line `return a.getZ() * 3` runs, the object will have the property `getZ` set.

1. `main` requires `a`
2. `a` requires `b`
3. `b` requires `a` and gets an object that is *currently* empty
4. `b` defines `getY` on its exports and returns
5. `a` defines `getX` and `getZ` on its exports (which is the exact same object that `b` already got a reference to!) and returns
6. `main` calls `a.getX()`
7. `a.getX` calls `b.getY`
8. `b.getY` only now accesses the property `getZ` of `a` which does exist by now (it was set in step 5).

Note that it would not have worked if we had written `const { getZ } = require('./a')` because then the `getZ` property would have been accessed already at step 3 when it wouldn't have existed yet.

But, similarly, it also would have stopped working if we had written `a.js` like this:

```js
const b = require('./b')

function getX () {
  return b.getY() * 2
}

function getZ () {
  return 5
}

module.exports = { getX, getZ }
```

The big difference here is that *we are now reassigning the exports object*! So, the object that `b` gets at step 3 is the original (empty) object, but we are then reassigning it to a new object (instead of modifying the existing object), and the code in `b` never has a chance to get a reference to that object! Then, you have this exact situation: A `require` gives you an empty object, and trying to call `a.getZ` will fail with `a.getZ is not a function` (because it is `undefined`).

(By the way, `module.exports = something` is *not* the same as `exports = something`, because the latter reassigns the local `exports` variable and does not change what other modules will see as exports from yours!)

My assumption right now is that you have a similar problem here - that the file that does the DB connection is requiring the file that *uses* the DB connection, but the other way round as well.

You now have two options:

- Replace `module.exports = { app, db }` with `exports.app = app; exports.db = db` or `Object.assign(exports, { app, db })` - both of which mutate the *existing* exports object instead of replacing it.
- Require one of the files at a later point in time, either by requiring it inside of another function or by creating a placeholder variable `let otherModule` and exporting an `init` method that actually fills it using `otherModule = require('./otherModule')` and then calling this `init` method in a second step after requiring, thereby decoupling the evaluating of the module code and the requiring of its dependencies, breaking the circular dependency.

The first option is probably the easiest, most immediate solution to the problem. But, I don't know the rest of your code, so there may be other obstacles that prevent this solution from being viable.

So, let me explain the second option in detail, because it can solve the issue often too.

Example of the second option:

```js
/* a.js */
let b

function getX () {
  return b.getY() * 2
}

function getZ () {
  return 5
}

function init () {
  b = require('./b')
}

module.exports = { init, getX, getZ }
```

```js
/* b.js */
const a = require('./a')

function getY = function () {
  return a.getZ() * 3
}

module.exports = { getY }
```

```js
/* main.js */
const a = require('./a')
a.init()

console.log(a.getX()) // Returns 30
```

This code now works *even though it reassigns `module.exports`*, because now things happen in a different order:

1. `main` requires `a`
2. `a` replaces its exports object with one that contains `init`, `getX` and `getZ` and returns [note that this part of the code previously ran much later]
3. `main` calls `a.init()`
4. `a.init` requires `b`
5. `b` requires `a` and gets its final exports object with all the methods [note that previously it got a not-yet-filled object because `a` was also not fully loaded yet!]
6. `b` replaces its exports object with one that contains `getY` and returns
7. `a.init` returns
8. `main` calls `a.getX()`
9. Everything works from now on because both `a` and `b` by now have references to each others' fully-filled exports objects already

The other way to implement the second option of "requiring at a later point in time" is to `require` the other module inside an exported function that is already used, but this can have its downsides (such as duplicate code if it is needed in many functions, and slightly slower execution because `require` has to be called over and over again). In our example, it would mean doing this:

```js
/* b.js */

function getY () {
  const a = require('./a')
  return a.getZ() * 3
}

module.exports = { getY }
```